# Callback function not waiting until jQuery fadeOut() completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, fadeout, jquery-callback

I'm trying to hide a spinner which always sits inside of a `div` with an id of "Loading". This is working fine however I've added a callback function which, in this case is simply an `alert()` however the `alert()` appears to fire before the `fadeOut()` has completed leaving me with the spinner's translucent background panel still visible behind the alert.

Any idea?

```
// Hide the spinner. 
function deactivate(callbackFn) {
    console.log('spinner deactivated');
    $("#Loading").fadeOut(removeSpinnerTag(callbackFn));
}

// Removes the spinner tag dynamically added to the DOM by the spinner.activate() method. 
function removeSpinnerTag(callbackFn) {
    $("#Loading div.spinner").remove();
    if (typeof (callbackFn) == 'function') {
        callbackFn();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#Loading").fadeOut(function() { removeSpinnerTag(callbackFn) });
```

You were executing `removeSpinnerTag()` instead of passing a reference to the function.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you, stupid mistake! Will accept this as the answer when stack lets me (too soon at the moment!).